# Why npm install failed : Error Etarget?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I am new in node. I try to run my first meanjs project. I have a package json file :

```
{
  "name": "notetest1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "mongodb": "~3.0.0",
    "monk": "~1.0.1"
  }
}
```

NodeJS

```
node -v
v4.1.1
```

NPM

```
 npm -version
 2.7.5
```

MongoDB

```
mongod -version
db version v3.0.2
git version: nogitversion
```

I want to install dependencies by running `npm install` command but i am getting some errors :

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.5
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: mongodb@'>=3.0.0 <3.1.0'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["0.9.4","0.9.4-4","0.9.3","0.9.1","0.9.2","0.9.6-7","0.9.6-8","0.9.6-9","0.9.6-10","0.9.6-11","0.9.6-12","0.9.6-13","0.9.6-14","0.9.6-15","0.9.6-16","0.9.6-17","0.9.6-18","0.9.6-19","0.9.6-20","0.9.6-21","0.9.6-22","0.9.6-23","0.9.7","0.9.7-0","0.9.7-1","0.9.7-1.1","0.9.7-1.2","0.9.7-1.3","0.9.7-1.4","0.9.7-2","0.9.7-2-1","0.9.7-2-2","0.9.7-2-3","0.9.7-2-4","0.9.7-2-5","0.9.7-3","0.9.7-3-1","0.9.7-3-2","0.9.7-3-3","0.9.7-3-4","0.9.7-3-5","0.9.8","0.9.8-1","0.9.8-2","0.9.8-3","0.9.8-4","0.9.8-5","0.9.8-6","0.9.8-7","0.9.9","0.9.9-1","0.9.9-2","0.9.9-3","0.9.9-4","0.9.9-5","0.9.9-6","0.9.9-7","0.9.9-8","1.0.0","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.1.0-beta","1.1.0","1.1.1","1.1.2","1.1.3","1.1.4","1.1.5","1.1.6","1.1.7","1.1.8","1.1.9","1.1.10","1.1.11","1.2.0","1.2.1","1.2.2","1.2.3","1.2.4","1.2.5","1.2.6","1.2.7","1.2.8","1.2.9","1.2.10","1.2.11","1.2.12","1.2.13","1.2.14","1.3.0","1.3.1","1.3.2","1.3.3","1.3.4","1.3.5","1.3.6","1.3.7","1.3.8","1.3.9","1.3.10","1.3.11","1.3.12","1.3.14","1.3.15","1.3.17","1.3.18","1.3.19","1.4.0-rc2","1.3.20","1.4.0-rc3","1.3.21","1.3.22","1.3.23","1.4.0-rc4","1.4.0-rc5","1.4.0-rc6","1.4.0-rc7","1.4.0-rc8","1.4.0-rc9","1.4.0-rc10","1.4.0","1.4.1","1.4.2","1.4.3","1.4.4","1.4.5","1.4.6","1.4.7","1.4.8","1.4.9","1.4.10","2.0.0-alpha1","1.4.11","1.4.12","1.4.14","1.4.15","1.4.16","1.4.17","2.0.0-alpha2","1.4.18","2.0.0","2.0.1","2.0.2","1.4.19","2.0.3","2.0.4","2.0.5","2.0.6","1.4.20","1.4.22","2.0.7","2.0.8","2.0.9","1.4.23","2.0.10","1.4.24","2.0.11","1.4.25","2.0.12","1.4.26","1.4.27","1.4.28","2.0.13","2.0.14","1.4.29","2.0.15","1.4.30","2.0.16","1.4.31","2.0.17","1.4.32","2.0.18","2.0.19","1.4.33","2.0.20","2.0.21","1.4.34","2.0.22","2.0.23","1.4.35","2.0.24","2.0.25","2.0.26","2.0.27","2.0.28","2.0.29","1.4.36","2.0.30","1.4.37","2.0.31","1.4.38","2.0.32","2.0.33","2.1.0-alpha","2.0.34","2.0.35","2.0.36","2.0.37","2.0.38","2.0.39","1.4.39","2.0.40","2.0.41","2.0.42","2.0.43","2.0.44","2.0.45"]
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'notetest1'
npm ERR! notarget
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a mongodb version that isn't actually available. Change the version to `x.x.x´ Or run`npm install mongodb --save` for it to be updated to your package.json

Answer (score 0):

There is no v3.0 of the [`mongodb` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) (this version is not related to the MongoDB server version). Change the line `"mongodb": "~3.0.0"` by `"mongodb": "~2.0.0"` for example or remove it and do a `npm install mongodb --save`.

Answer (score 0):

The `~` matches to the nearest patch version. Try using the `^` in package.json

```
"mongodb": "^3.0.0"
```

Or just fetch the latest version by running `npm install --save` which will update the `package.json` file automatically.